# Does QExo XQuery string-join work?

Tags: xquery

When I run string-join, I get a weird output like this:

```
<clinic>
  <Name>Olive Street Pediatrics</Name>
  <Address>1500 Olive St, Los Angeles, CA 90015</Address>
  <PhoneNumberList>'\u04bc','\u04e4'</PhoneNumberList>
  <NumberOfPatientGroups>4</NumberOfPatientGroups>
</clinic>
```

Notice the PhoneNumberList.

The output reported by Altova XMLSpy looks correct (using the same XQuery file)

```
<clinic>
    <Name>Olive Street Pediatrics</Name>
    <Address>1500 Olive St, Los Angeles, CA 90015</Address>
    <PhoneNumberList>213-512-7457,213-512-7465</PhoneNumberList>
    <NumberOfPatientGroups>4</NumberOfPatientGroups>
</clinic>
```

Does string-join work on Qexo?

- Here is my [XML file](http://share1t.com/hqr2f9)
- Here is my [Xquery file](http://share1t.com/fxcd1x)

I use kawa-1.9.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

In this case Altova is producing the correct result.  The bug is with Qexo.

Running the query in another processor (XQSharp) produced the same result as Altova.